# foreign array elements within array within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of skills like so:

```
var a_skill = ['problem solving', 'collaboration', 'public speaking'];
```

I also have an object array like so:

```
var o_job[0] = {title: "developer", skills:[skill[0], skill[2]]};
var o_job[1] = {title: "project manager", skills:[skill[0], skill[1]]};
```

however this doesn't work. How do I make it so a job object array element can create an array from elements of an outside array? (whew that's a mouthful) The main issue seems to be the array of outside array elements since when I take that part out, it starts working again

Comment: outside you are using `a_skill` inside you are using `skill`, that is a problem

Comment: If you have an error message from this please post it. If not, please describe the incorrect behavior that occurs.

Answer (score 2):

`skill` doesnt look like it's defined.

```
var a_skill = ['problem solving', 'collaboration', 'public speaking'];

var o_job[0] = {title: "developer", skills:[a_skill[0], a_skill[2]]};
var o_job[1] = {title: "project manager", skills:[a_skill[0], a_skill[1]]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most appropriate way to do this would be to encapsulate the external array in an object as well, so that you can insert into it using an accessor. An alternative would be to make a static class with helper methods to do this. Also make sure that your arrays are all declared at appropriate access levels (private, public etc.)

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it, unfortunately I'm just starting with javascript (I could probably do it in Java). Thanks for the advice- I didn't know there were scope declarations in javascript.

Comment: Oops, I didnt notice the javascript tag. You are correct javascript does not have scope declaration, all variables declared outside of functions are global.